# Scrolling inside a TextArea Bootstrap using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have created a component which manages scrolling. So far I have been able to scroll the entire window using the following method.

```
 window.scrollBy(0, speed)
```

Moving the entire window seems rather unnecessary, I wanted to scroll within the textarea. I'm not sure how I can achieve this using React. Is it possible to use Ref's to do the same?

```
<textarea 
   ref={this.textAreaRef}
   maxLength="25000"
   style={{tabSize:10}}
   class="col-12 form-control-lg"
   id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
</textarea>
```

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

assuming this.textAreaRef is created with React.createRef(), the textarea has a scrollbar and the component has been rendered:

```
this.textAreaRef.current.scrollBy(x, y)
```

You're passing the speed parameter as Y. Not sure if that's intended.

Comment: Yes it does work, however it doesn't scroll the entire length of the textArea. Would I have to use a different function for the same?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Hence the method name it will just scroll by the amount of x or y you pass in. You may want to use the scrollTo(x, y) method instead.

I'd suggest you look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element and search the page for "scroll". There are a lot more options.